# RaphaelJS Move Rotated elements

Tags: javascript, raphael, jquery-svg

I have a rect rotated by 45degrees when I try and move it in a straight line using the normal move drag functionality it moves with the 45degree rotation. I've seen a lot of posts regarding this and that this is intended to work like this but I haven't found a simple way to fix this.

I know about the raphael.free_transform.js plugin but I don't need 90% of the script.

From other posts I know I'm supposed to use Math.atan2 but alas my Math skills aren't that great.

My current move function looks like this:

```
function (dx, dy) {
        var att = this.type == "rect" ? {x: this.ox + dx, y: this.oy + dy} : {cx: this.ox + dx, cy: this.oy + dy}; 
        this.attr(att);
        for (var i = connections.length; i--;) {
            r.connection(connections[i]);
        }
        r.safari();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use "transform" method instead of simply changing x-y attrs.

```
var data = {};
var R = Raphael('raphael', 500, 500);
var rect = R.rect(100, 100, 100, 50).attr({fill: "#aa5555"}).transform('r45');
var default_transform = rect.transform();

var onmove = function (dx, dy) {
    rect.transform(default_transform + 'T' + dx + ',' + dy);
};
var onstart = function () {};
var onend = function () {
    default_transform = rect.transform();
};

rect.drag(onmove, onstart, onend);
```

**I have created a live demo for you on JSfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/pybBq/

Please note that you have to use big **T** letter in transform string (not small **t**) to make transformation absolute and not relative. Please read Raphael's docs on transform for more info: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform

Comment: it works but still not 100% when you select->move->select->move the rect keeps popping away from the actual position

Comment: OK check again JSfiddle (I updated "onend" method) > http://jsfiddle.net/pybBq/1/